# Recursive formula for mathematical expression

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Assume that $\alpha , n,\lambda \in \mathbb{N}$,and $f$,$g$ two real valued functions defined on $\mathbb{N}$. Function $W$ is given by the following formula.

\begin{equation}
W(n) = \max_{1 \leq \lambda \leq n} \bigg\{ \sum^{\min\{\lambda + \alpha , n \}}_{k=\lambda} f(k) + \sum^{n}_{k=\min\{\lambda + \alpha , n \}+1}g(k) \bigg\}
\end{equation}

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to write this expression into a more compact recursive form, like writing $W(n)$ as a function of $W(n-1)$ and maybe some other terms. Is it possible? I can't figure out how to make $n-1$ appear and get a nice recursion, since $n$ is inside the minimum. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: it's a constant integer. Basically the min is used to compensate for the fact than $n$ may be greater or smaller than $\lambda + \alpha$.